# "be governed from" vs "be governed by"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I just read the following sentence on *Economist*,

> Their success is an implicit rebuke to China’s autocratic regime, and an obvious reason for them to resist being governed **from** Beijing.

But "be governed by" sounds more natural to me. Are there any differences between "be governed by" and "be governed from"?

Answer (score 1):

**From** and **by** give the sentences different meanings and both are correct:

> *to resist being governed **from** Beijing.*

The preposition "from" indicates an origin - it tells us the origin of the action. From which place does the governing take place? It takes place from Beijing.

Compare:
*I saw him **from** the tower* - Where were you? You were on the tower and you saw him.

> *to resist being governed **by** Beijing.*

The preposition "by" indicates the agent - the thing that does the action:

Compare:
*"I was kidnapped **by** bandits"* - Who did the kidnapping? The bandits did the kidnapping.

In *to resist being governed **by** Beijing*, Beijing does not mean "the city of Beijing" - it means "the government, which is situated in Beijing".

This use of Beijing is a figure of speech called "synecdoche":

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche):

> Synecdoche (/sɪˈnɛkdəki/) is a type of metonymy: it is a figure of speech in which a term for a part of something is used to refer to the whole, or vice versa.
>
> Examples of common English synecdoches include **suits** for businessmen, **wheels** for automobile, and **boots** for soldiers.
>
> Another example is the use of government buildings to refer to their resident agencies or bodies, such as “The Pentagon” for the United States Department of Defense. An example from British English is using "Downing Street" as a metonym for "the Office of the Prime Minister".

Here Beijing = the Communist Party of China

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this relates to Hong Kong or somewhere that is not Mainland China. If so the reason for from over by is rather plain. They are emphasising foreign rule from somewhere abroad. Take this sentence for example “The Irish sought to stop any further governance from Westminster”. This emphasises the British governments seat rather than the British nation as a whole, and also emphasises their adventitiousness to Ireland. The usage of from with the seat of a government is common and is simply a stylistic difference from the usage with by. “Ireland did not want to be governed by Britain any longer.
“The south did not want any more interference from Washington” vs “The south did not want any interference by the north” similar meanings but just slightly different emphasises.

Just to clarify: Use **by** with the nations name and **from** with the capital/seat of governments name, unless there be an obvious not to do so.